# pivot df with duplicates as new rows

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

Evening, I have a dataframe that I want to reshape. there are duplicate id vars for some columns, and i want the duplicate values to appear as new rows

my data looks like this, and i want to have the ids as a row, with the group as column, and the choices as the values. if there are multiple choices picked per id within a group, then the row should be replicated as shown below. when I use pivot I end up just getting the mean or sum of the combined values e.g. 11.5 for id i1, group1. all tips very welcome thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['i1','i1','i1','i2','i2','i2','i2','i2','i3','i3'],
    'group': ['group1','group1','group2','group3','group1','group2','group2','group3','group1','group2'],
    'choice':[12,11,12,14,11,19,9,7,8,9]})
```

```
pd.DataFrame({'id': ['i1','i1','i2','i2','i3'],
              'group1': [12,11,11,np.nan,8],
              'group2': [12,np.nan,19,9,9],
              'group3':[np.nan,np.nan,14,7,np.nan]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.droplevel.html):

```
g = df.groupby(['id','group']).cumcount().add(1)

df = (df.set_index(['id','group', g])['choice']
        .unstack(level=1)
        .droplevel(level=1)
        .rename_axis(None,axis=1)
        .reset_index())
print (df)
   id  group1  group2  group3
0  i1    12.0    12.0     NaN
1  i1    11.0     NaN     NaN
2  i2    11.0    19.0    14.0
3  i2     NaN     9.0     7.0
4  i3     8.0     9.0     NaN
```